# Rendering multiple components in React js

Tags: reactjs

Community, I rendered more than one component from a single page and the problem I receive is:

```
[./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'Greeting' is not exported from './components/Home'.]
```

Can anybody tell me why?

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Home, Page, Greeting } from "./components/Home";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
      <Page />
      <Greeting />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import React from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        <h1>Its a box man!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        <h1>Its a second box man! from the other Component</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Greeting = () => {
  return <h1>Hello again</h1>;
};

export { Home, Page, Greeting };
```

*The aim to practice two components from the same page, rather than just separating them.

Comment: And the error is ... ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot ./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'Greeting' is not exported from './components/Home'.

Comment: Just add export... Export const greeting

Comment: Your code is working completely fine, no need to add defaults or any other exports. I've tested it personally. You're missing something else. Can you show your project structure? Also, you're importing React twice.

Comment: I removed one of them and still doesn't work

Comment: @Spactex Like I told you, your code is working completely fine. Post your project structure and the place where you import App.js, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to export all components one by one in Home.js like this:

export class Home...
export class Page...
export const Greeting...

And after that delete this line:

export { Home, Page, Greeting };

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const Greeting = () => {
  return <h1>Hello again</h1>;
};
```

to

```
export const Greeting = () => {
  return <h1>Hello again</h1>;
};
```

and your issue should be resolved

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't.

Comment: do as @Prime said
```
export default { Home, Page, Greeting}
```

and post the error here if coming any

Comment: post error which you are facing after advice.
need exact error after changes being made

Comment: --- Latest update ---, issue resolved and Spactex got a reasoning also of `export default` and `export`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `Home.js`. If you export module as default, you can import without parenthesis `{}`. But if you export without default, you have to import using parenthesis.

```
export default { Home, Page, Greeting };
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, I solved it but make no sense to me. I exported one of them as default and the other two in { } and I imported them in App.js the default in a line and the other two {}, it worked but make no sense what was that.

Comment: Check this article. https://javascript.info/import-export
It will give you more explanation. :)

Comment: Could you add the explanation from the article to your answer? That way, if the article ever goes offline, this answer will still have that useful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and there was no problems except if these are not typos:

- you haven't imported react in your App.js
- you've imported react twice in your Home.js

The only problem I can think of is that you have forgotten to save `Home.js`.
If you've saved `Home.js`:

1. exit you're dev server using `ctrl + c` and start it again and see if the problem is resolved.
2. try removing Greeting Component and let us know if you still get errors.